# Faster backtrace for call graph generation?

Tags: debugging, gdb, llvm, backtrace, call-graph

I use the following approach to generate call graphs.

https://github.com/tarun27sh/gdb_graphs

But gdb is dramatically (x100) slowed down by backtrace. Is there a much faster way to generate call graphs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a much faster way to generate call graphs?

Of course there is (using GDB for this is completely inappropriate).

The simplest solution is to use GCC `-finstrument-functions` to insert a call at every function entry and exit, and implement the data collection in these "injected" functions. There is an example [here](https://balau82.wordpress.com/2010/10/06/trace-and-profile-function-calls-with-gcc/).

Comment: This example uses function pointer which is not readable. How to use readable function name?

Comment: @user1424739 Which part of "To understand the addresses, the “addr2line” tool can be used" you didn't understand?

Comment: I use Mac. I don’t think binutils is well supported on Mac.

Comment: @user1424739 Google search suggests that Mac OSX has an `atos` tool that provides equivalent functionality.

Comment: function names can be resolved with `dladdr`: https://cmdlinelinux.blogspot.com/2020/01/i-have-been-chasing-for-toolcompiler.html

Answer (score 0):

Since you post this question on SO and tag it with [llvm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/llvm) I assume that means you're looking for a programming solution using LLVM.

Write a pass that transforms each function in your program to add three new instructions before each call. Something like this:

```
struct RecordCallGraph : public PassInfoMixin<RecordCallGraph> {
  RecordCallGraph() = default;
  PreservedAnalyses run(Function &F, FunctionAnalysisManager &FAM);
};
```

You need to implement that run(), which will be about 15 lines of code. Scan the basic blocks in the function, check whether each instruction `isa<CallBase>` and if it is, then insert a little extra code before the CallBase. (CallBase is the base class of instructions that call functions.) You insert a a call to your new new function, `void emitTraceInfo(char* caller, char* called)` or something like that. Since LLVM IR is typesafe you need to cast the caller (`&F`) and the called function (`callBase->getCalledValue()`) to the right type for your function (`char*` in the example).

The simplest way to get that cast is likely to be `CastInst::Create(CastInst::BitCast, &F, charStarType, "", callBase)`, which creates a new cast from `&F` to `charStarType` and inserts it immediately before `callBase`.

Finally you have to implement your new `emitTraceInfo` and link it into the program. It will be called each and every time one function calls another, and can record the call. You'll find it about a hundred times faster than gdb. The slowest part may be to write the 16-odd bytes to file.

Comment: I can insert code directly to the ll file converted from the bitcode. What is the code in the IR assembly language? In addition, how to trace at the code block level instead of just at the function level? Thanks.

Comment: Two `bitcast` instructions and one `call`, each with two arguments. All six arguments depend on the surroundings, of course.

Comment: I'm not sure whether the new loop manager supports basic block passes in the way the old one did, I've never tried to do that, but it's easy enough to loop over the blocks given a `Function&` F: `for(auto & b : F.getBasicBlockList()) {…`